# I am trying to move a file from one path to another in PHP without success

Tags: php, file, copy

I am trying to move a file `'avatars/generic.jpg'` to a folder that has a dynamic variable in it - `$_SESSION['user_id']` - the path would look like this

```
avatars/$_SESSION['user_id']/generic.jpg
```

but I can't get it to work using the copy function in PHP. I have tried curly braces etc around the session variable without success....

Any suggestions?

Comment: is this folder avatars/$_SESSION['user_id'] already there?

Comment: Yes. Made sure of that. Basically on signing up to my site, a folder is created in the folder 'avatars', named after the users ID. The users id is also stored in $_SESSION['user_id']. Next I want to place a generic avatar icon which is in 'avatars' into the just made folder

Comment: Use move_uploaded_file and take heed of what @rakeshjain has pointed out.

Comment: Did you check your error log for any particular errors related to this?

Comment: Does move_uploaded_file, only apply to an uploaded file though? There is no uploaded file in this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
    copy("avatars/generic.jpg", "avatars/" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "/generic.jpg"); 
?>
```

By using the '.' operator for concatenation you don't have to worry about escaping.

Answer (score 1):

kindly use . as to concatinate  the variables

```
"...avatars/".$_SESSION['user_id']."/generic.jpg ";
```